# How to import Google Maps route into Sygic iOS App?

Tags: ios, google-maps, import, sygic

I'm trying to import a route that I made into my Sygic iOS App. I have used ITN Converter and created .kml file. I tried to save it into Sygic App through iTunes but no lock. I have Sygic 15.4 and ITN Converter 1.87.

Answer (score 1):

Sygic app supports *.sif itineraries (json file format). Please convert the google maps route to this format and you should be able to load the route in Sygic app.
You can find more info in the following link: http://www.sygic.com/developers/professional-navigation-sdk/ios/custom-url